# Is it bad to have hamburger menu with back naviation button for inner pages

Tags: website-design, material-design, google-materials-design

We are using hamburger menu on all page even page are inner pages. I want to know if this is bad user experience to show back navigation button with hamburger menu in web? below is an example

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example with a screenshot, and why would you think it is a bad UX?

Answer (score 2):

I think if there are a few steps in this process you should use a **breadcrumb navigation**, and increase the size of to make it more clickable.
[image: breadcrumb navigation]

Also, you could definitely just use a side bar navigation as this is desktop and you have plenty of real estate there. No real need for a hamburger there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's kind of confused. What is the reason for this? If you want to guide user to previous screen you've already have breadcrumbs for this.

If you're worried about mobile version navigation you can put it underneath like I did once on my project

[image: hamburger and back button mobile]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's bad. I would focus on visually enhancing these components so that the user knows they are buttons to be pressed/clicked. Based on the screenshot provided, the back button could be mistaken for a an aesthetic element as opposed to a functional one.